# How to test Dao methods which return DataSource.Factory?

Tags: android, android-room, android-testing, android-paging

After shifting from `SqliteOpenHelper` to `room` in my app, I've trying to write tests for the `DAO` class.

My DAO looks something like this:

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM cards")
    fun getAllCards(): List<CardData>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertCard(vararg cardData: CardData): List<Long>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM cards ORDER BY isRead ASC, id DESC")
    fun getItemList(): DataSource.Factory<Int, CardData>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM cards where instr(title, :query) > 0 ORDER BY isRead ASC, id DESC")
    fun getItemList(query: String): DataSource.Factory<Int, CardData>

    @Query("UPDATE cards set isRead = 1 where title = :title")
    fun markRead(title: String): Int
```

While writing test for `getAllCards`, `insertCard` and `markRead` is trivial, I am still not sure how do I test the apis which return `DataSource.Factory`, i.e `getItemList` apis.

After searching on internet, I couldn't find anything related to this.

Can someone please help.

Comment: Hi @Yashavi, have you been able to get a solution to this, other than creating a class to implement the interface and returning _mocks_ for it's functions?

Comment: @Enoobong:  Hey, no. I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 7):

this is how I did:

```
val factory = dao.getItemList()
val list = (factory.create() as LimitOffsetDataSource).loadRange(0, 10)
```

Quoting CommonsWare

> If you use paging with Room and have a @Dao method return a DataSource.Factory, the generated code uses an internal class named LimitOffsetDataSource to perform the SQLite operations and fulfill the PositionalDataSource contract.

source: https://commonsware.com/AndroidArch/previews/paging-beyond-room#head206